# /dev/dvb permissions

Tags: permissions, dvb

Seen a few posts on this but I can't seem to get any of the suggested solutions to work (rc.local, init.d).

I need to give my user permissions to use dvb devices on startup. I can run `chmod -R chris /dev/dvb` manually with success, but it would be a lot easier if this was handled automatically at boot. I dont really need to own them I just need permisssions, so whichever solution is best.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: What are the output of `ls -l /dev/dvb` ?

Comment: chris@Server:~$ ls -l /dev/dvb
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 chris root 120 Jan 15 19:08 adapter0

Comment: This is after I have already ran the chmod. Would normally be root.